# How to implement a "selective" clipToBounds for a UIView, i.e. clip some subviews but not others

Tags: iphone, uiview, subview

I want to clip some of a view's subviews to the bounds of the view and not others. Any ideas as to how to set about implementing this quickly and easily.

For context: I have a UIScrollView with a set of subviews that can be dragged off the view. When dragging them off the view, I want the subview NOT TO BE CLIPPED. Otherwise I do want them clipped.

- If I perform [view setClipToBounds: YES] before laying out the subviews all is well until I come to drag the subview off. And if, when dragging begins, I perform [view setClipToBounds: NO] at touchesBegan:withEvent and [view setClipToBounds: YES] at touchesEnded:withEvent:, then the scrollview redraws during the drag, so the previously clipped subviews appear.
- One approach I have tried, but not got to work, is moving the subview from the scrollview to the scrollview's superview as soon as dragging begins (in the subview's touchesBegan:withEvent). However, when the view is moved from one view to another, it appears to lose track of touches and dragging is ends.

Comment: why don't you implement that in the UIScrollViewDelegate methods?

Comment: You should put your "Update" in an answer and accept it.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I've taken your advice and done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem in the following way. When the subview of the scrollview receives a touchesBegan:withEvent: I set the alpha of that subview to 0.0. I then create an identical subview and add it to the scrollview's superview. For the initial position I use the following:

```
CGPoint newOrigin = [self origin];
newOrigin.x = newOrigin.x + [[self superview] origin].x;
newOrigin.y = newOrigin.y + [[self superview] origin].y - [(UIScrollView*)[self superview] contentOffset].y;
[newSubview setOrigin: newOrigin];  // setOrigin is defined in a category on UIView - it does what you'd expect
```

(Note - if you don't compensate for the scrollview content offset you can get puzzling behaviour...)

My touchesMoved:withEvent method moves the subview (as per normal for implementing dragging) and then touchesEnded:withEvent removes the extra subview from the scrollview's superview and sets the alpha of the initial subview back to 1.0. So, in effect, the additional subview, piggy backs on the invisible subview.